# user-scalable=no but still able to scale entire page on web map application?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, mapbox

I have a web application that is essentially a map (mapbox) with some d3.js points overlayed, filters, etc.

My issue is that when zooming in on the map using pinch (mobile), when I accidentally pinch over one of the points, or one of the map pop-ups, the entire page zooms (i.e. scaling). This is a fairly common occurrence. I only want user to be able to zoom the map, not the page itself.

I've implemented:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I also tried `user-scalable=0`

And still the behavior persists. I've also tried this:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
},{passive: false});

document.getElementById('map')
 .addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){e.stopPropagation()}, false);
```

But this is cumbersome and doesn't exactly work the greatest because it involved limiting event-listeners one element at a time.  Shouldn't the `user-scalable` argument in the HTML be enough? I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Try `0` instead of `no`, just to rule out it's not just that particular browser not respecting the letter value.

Comment: hmm, no luck still even with 0.

Comment: Remember to mention that in the post, not just in a comment.

Comment: What browser, its a really important detail because [iOS 10 ignores that attribute](https://webkit.org/blog/7367/new-interaction-behaviors-in-ios-10/) and I highly suggest that you try to avoid it, it is a huge frustration for many users. https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/80487/46091

Answer (score 1):

Mobile browsers have no effect on user scalable because they over ride it to get people responsive experience on the mobiles.
Sites like google maps also zoom when we pinch in the site(expanding the ui elements as well as the map)

One way to override this response is to detect the [pinch gesture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Pinch_zoom_gestures) and then re zoom  the page to the normal level  by a function such as:

`function toggleZoomScreen() {document.body.style.zoom = "100%”;}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This does not work, because on mobile, it disables the zooming of the map (i.e. pinch zooming).

Comment: On mobile devices many websites tend to use double click to allow zooming in map

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the user-scalable argument in the HTML be enough?

Depends on the browser/device. There are not many legitimately cases where zooming should be disallowed, so browsers will ignore it. Some browsers like Safari uses heuristics based on text size to decide if it should zoom or not... (where the solution is to set font-size to 17px or higher on input elements to prevent zoom)

1. First strategy would be to call preventDefault() on all mouse
   events, like mouseup, mousedown, et.al (not just the touch events)
   until you are able to block the zoom.
2. Second strategy is to take into account the zoom and scale the
   images and point locations by the amount of zoom...

(Probably also want to take into account window.devicePixelRatio when scaling.)